# I don't understand what the "shift" and "scale" parameters in the NormContinuous field in PMML code are responsible for?

Tags: python, keras, pmml

I have a neural network (not mine) trained in STATISTICA and saved in PMML v 3.0, I am trying to rewrite it into keras, but I have faced with some difficulties:

1) As I understood from the code, the input data should be normalized to the interval from 0 to 1, but I don’t understand for what purpose the "shift" and "scale" parameters are needed.

2) In the neural network there is an input parameter "MRI" which can take one of three values ​​'1 or 2 or 3". For this parameter there are three input neurons. Do I understand correctly that if in the input data we get the value of "MRI" equal to 1, then the first neuron will receive 1, and the other two will receive 0?

1)

```
<NormContinuous field="CORT_M2" shift="-1.29449838187702e-002" scale="1.61812297734628e-003">
<LinearNorm orig="8.00000000000000e+000" norm="0.000000"/>
<LinearNorm orig="6.26000000000000e+002" norm="1.000000"/>
</NormContinuous>
```

2)

```
<DataField name="MRI" optype="categorical">
<Value value="1"/>
<Value value="2"/>
<Value value="3"/>
</DataField>
...
...
<NeuralInput id="6">
<DerivedField>
<NormDiscrete field="MRI" value="1"/>
</DerivedField>
</NeuralInput>
<NeuralInput id="7">
<DerivedField>
<NormDiscrete field="MRI" value="2"/>
</DerivedField>
</NeuralInput>
<NeuralInput id="8">
<DerivedField>
<NormDiscrete field="MRI" value="3"/>
</DerivedField>
</NeuralInput>
</NeuralInputs>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PMML 3.0, the `NormContinuous` element does not specify `shift` nor `scale` attributes: http://dmg.org/pmml/v3-0/Transformations.html

They must be some STATISTICA inventions.